# CRUD operations don't work in my web api, presumably mongodb problem

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api app and CRUD operations aren't being performed, though I have all necessary controllers. I think it's `mongodb` related issue; I have "test" database with "users" collection.

I'm new to `.NET` so I made tons of mistakes,this is my `program.cs` code:

```
using metanit.Controllers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.Configure<PersonDatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("PersonDatabase"));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<PersonService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and this is PersonController:

```
using metanit.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace metanit.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly PersonService _personService;

        public PersonController(PersonService personService) =>
            _personService = personService;

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<Person>> Get() =>
            await _personService.Find();

        [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Person>> Get(string id)
        {
            var person = await _personService.Find(id);

            if (person is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return person;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Person newPerson)
        {
            await _personService.InsertOneAsync(newPerson);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = newPerson.Id }, newPerson);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, Person updatedPerson)
        {
            var person = await _personService.Find(id);

            if (person is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            updatedPerson.Id = person.Id;

            await _personService.ReplaceOneAsync(id, updatedPerson);

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            var person = await _personService.Find(id);

            if (person is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            await _personService.DeleteOneAsync(id);

            return NoContent();
        }


    }
    public class PersonDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = null!;

        public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;

        public string GetCollection { get; set; } = null!;
    }
    public class PersonService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Person> _personCollection;

        public PersonService(
            IOptions<PersonDatabaseSettings> personDatabaseSettings)
        {
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                personDatabaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

            var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(
                personDatabaseSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

            _personCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Person>(
                personDatabaseSettings.Value.GetCollection);
        }

        public async Task<List<Person>> Find() =>
            await _personCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();

        public async Task<Person?> Find(string id) =>
            await _personCollection.Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        public async Task InsertOneAsync(Person newPerson) =>
            await _personCollection.InsertOneAsync(newPerson);

        public async Task ReplaceOneAsync(string id, Person updatedPerson) =>
            await _personCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.Id == id, updatedPerson);

        public async Task DeleteOneAsync(string id) =>
            await _personCollection.DeleteOneAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

and

```
appsettings.json
```

```
{
  "PersonDatabase": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "test",
    "GetCollection": "users"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I tried to connect my app to `mongo db` but CRUD operations don't work. I'm new to `.NET` so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: "not working" is not a proper problem description ... Attach a debugger to your backend and check if the request handlers are even executed, and if yes, if an error happens ...

Comment: Well, are you getting any error or what exactly not working? Did you able to connect with the mongodb connection successfully?

Answer (score 1):

> I have web api app and CRUD operations aren't performed, though I have
> all necessary controllers. I think it's mongodb related issue; I have
> "test" database with "users" collection.

Well, from your shared code snippet, there might be couple of reasons why you are not able to connect mongo db instance with your asp.net core project, I am seeing, you haven't registered a important service, in program.cs, please refer to my program.cs section.

Apart from that, make sure, you have [successfully installed](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/installation/) and created few object in your [mongo db instance](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/installation/). You can follow be steps.

Create MongoDb and Collection:

[image]

Insert few object into table :

You can do as following

[image]
[image]

**Note:** Mongo is case sensitive, all property name should be in lower case, mising of both might cause deserializaton error of 500, be aware of that.

appsettings.json configuration:

Make sure, your appsetting for Mongo Db configuration are correct, you can refer to following:

```
"PersonDatabaseSettings": {
    "CollectionName": "Persons",
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "PersonDb"
  },
```

[image]

Note: My collection name is Persons, my databaseName is PersonDb which listening to port  `"mongodb://localhost:27017"`. Make sure, your configuration are correct.

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.Configure<PersonDatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("PersonDatabaseSettings"));



// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPersonDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
            sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<PersonDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<PersonService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

**Note:** Above configuration are mandaroty in order to run the sample.

Demo Model:

```
 public class Person
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Mondo Collection Configuration:

```
public class PersonDatabaseSettings : IPersonDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string CollectionName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPersonDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string CollectionName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** Make sure you have registered above service in program.cs

Person Service With Mongo Client:

```
public class PersonService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Person> _personCollection;
        public PersonService(IPersonDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

            _personCollection = database.GetCollection<Person>(settings.CollectionName);

        }
        public async Task<List<Person>> Find() =>
            await _personCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();

        public async Task<Person?> Find(string id) =>
            await _personCollection.Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        public async Task InsertOneAsync(Person newPerson) =>
            await _personCollection.InsertOneAsync(newPerson);

        public async Task ReplaceOneAsync(string id, Person updatedPerson) =>
            await _personCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.Id == id, updatedPerson);

        public async Task DeleteOneAsync(string id) =>
            await _personCollection.DeleteOneAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        

    }
```

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly PersonService _personService;

        public PersonController(PersonService personService) =>
            _personService = personService;

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<Person>> Get()
        {
            return await _personService.Find();
        }

    }
```

Output:

Get Request:
[image]

[image]

Post Request:

[image]

**Note:** As you can see I have successfully getting data from API using mongo collection and creating new object into it. Please [read carefully the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#prerequisites) if you encounter any issue.